# How can I wait for an external started job with DRMAA?

Tags: java, sungridengine, drmaa

I want to wait for a job to finish which has been submitted externally.

My first idea was to get the jobID by calling `qstat` and then executing `session.wait(jobID, Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER);`. But this doesn't work. Are there any other ideas except calling `qstat` until the job isn't listed anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain exactly what doesn't work about `session.wait(jobId, Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER)`? That would also be my inclination and allows you to retrieve the job's return code.

There's something [here](http://arc.liv.ac.uk/pipermail/gridengine-users/2010-September/032018.html) that might be relevant; it suggests using `synchronize` instead of `wait`:

```
session.synchronize(Collections.singletonList(jobId),
                       Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER, false); 
int status = session.getJobProgramStatus(jobId);
```

Otherwise, I'd you could add something to the job to record / signal its completion?

Comment: When I call `session.wait(jobId, Session.TIMEOUT_WAIT_FOREVER)` I get the following: `org.ggf.drmaa.InvalidJobException: The job specified by the 'jobid' does not exist.`
I also tried `synchronize`, but it doesn't really wait until the job has finished.